multilevel moderated mediation with Lavaan in R - failed to converge
This is a repeated measure study, we have X, Y, Mediator, and a moderator, which we hypothesis can moderate the mediation relationship. So I have level 1 and level 2 for between subjects and within subjects. But when I fit the model below, I got the error below:

lavaan WARNING:
model syntax contains variance/covariance/intercept formulas
involving (an) exogenous variable(s): [Moderator
Med_Mod]; These variables will now be treated
as random introducing additional free parameters. If you wish to
treat those variables as fixed, remove these formulas from the
model syntax. Otherwise, consider adding the fixed.x = FALSE
option. Warning in lavaan::lavaan(model = mediation_model, data = df, cluster = "ID",  :   lavaan WARNING:
the optimizer warns that a solution has NOT been found! Warning in lavaan::lavaan(model = mediation_model, data = df, cluster = "ID",  :
lavaan WARNING: estimation of the baseline model failed.

Is it because this model is too complicated for our data? Any suggestion for a solution? Thank you so much for your time and help!!!
df$Med_Mod  <-
  df$Mediator * df$Moderator

mediation_model <- 
 '   
  level:1
  # y 
  Y ~ cprime * Moderator
  Y ~ b * X
  Y ~ bprime * Med_Mod
  
  X ~ a * Mediator
  X ~~ Med_Mod
  Moderator ~~ Med_Mod
  
  b_med := b + bprime 
  ind_med_within := b_med * a 
  ind_all_within :=  b * a
  ind_diff_within := ind_med_within - ind_all_within

  level:2 
  # y 
  Y ~ cprime_2 * Moderator
  Y ~ b_2_btw * X
  Y ~ bprime_2 * Med_Mod
  
  X ~ a_2 * Mediator
  X ~~ Med_Mod
  Moderator ~~ Med_Mod
  
  b_med_btw := b_2_btw + bprime_2
  ind_med_btw := b_med_btw * a_2 
  ind_all_btw :=  b_2_btw * a_2
  ind_diff_btw := ind_med_btw - ind_all_btw
'

mediation_fit <- sem(mediation_model, data = df,estimator="ML",cluster = c("ID"),se = "robust") #
options(digits=10)
summary(mediation_fit, standardized = TRUE,nd=10)


Hi, how many observations do you have at both levels?

I think you are mistakenly regressing the predictor (X) on the mediator, rather than the other way around.  Please include a path diagram, corresponding to your fitted model.  See examples of different moderated mediation models in this tutorial: https://doi.org/10.1080/00273170701341316

I have around 40 subjects, within each subjects, there are 40 trials for each condition ( X = 1 and X = 2).
